# Php foreach loop combine two values

Tags: php, foreach

I the following example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 8
            [users] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 8
            [users] => 18,19
        )

)
```

I need to run foreach loop and end up with something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 8
            [users] => 1,8
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [user_id] => 8
            [users] => 18,19,8
        )

)
```

So that [user_id] and [users] are combined into [users]

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not some place to dump your to-do lists.

Comment: As easy as `foreach($arr as $i => $v) $arr[$i]->users[] = $arr[$i]->user_id;` Was it really that difficult? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach,

```
foreach( $arrObjects as $object ) {
    $object->users = $object->'users'.','.$object->user_id;
}
```

You should try to figure out first how you are going to approach it and post what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Alko If the answer works for you then accept it please